# Auto dependency resolver eclipse java code

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, resolver

I am currently trying to use a large collection of different java systems, called a corpus, for my research. However before I can use all these systems I have to build them one by one. This is very time consuming, so I was wondering if someone knows a great way to be able to build and if necessary resolve all the dependencies that have not been found yet. These dependencies can occure between the systems in the corpus or between a system in the corpus and a plugin that can be loaded by Eclipse.

I have been searching on stack overflow for this kind of functionality however if you search for dependency resolver you only get problems of unresolved dependencies.

Anyone has any idea whether such a program/plugin exists?
Or any smart ideas to import all the java projects and build them?

Thanks in advance.

Dennis